# how can i convert local coordinate of MouseEvent to scene coordinate of MouseEvent? in JAVAFX

Tags: javafx, coordinates, javafx-8

sources :

```
    flowLine = new Line();
    flowLine.setStrokeWidth(3);
    flowLine.setStroke(Color.RED);
    flowGroup.getChildren().addAll(flowLine);

    targetNodeItem.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mEvent) {

            drawPoint = new Point2D(mEvent.getSceneX(), mEvent.getSceneY());
            startX = drawPoint.getX();
            startY = drawPoint.getY();
        }           
    });

    targetNodeItem.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mEvent) {

            flowLine.setStartX(startX);
            flowLine.setStartY(startY);
            flowLine.setEndX(mEvent.getSceneX());
            flowLine.setEndY(mEvent.getSceneY());
        }
    });
```

targetNodeItem is the node.

I want to drag from that node and generate FlowLine, but the coordinates of FlowLine which is generated as an image(http://2url.kr/2lfjlsfa) are incorrect.

==================================================================================

check this out ->>> http://youtu.be/iZOL0Fs-umk

help me please

Comment: your link doesn't work for me.

Comment: http://2url.kr/2lfjlsfa <- img link

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me to draw a line without coordinate issues...

I used:

```
public class MouseDrag extends Application
{
    private Point2D drawPoint;
    private double startX;
    private double startY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);

        Group flowGroup = new Group();        
        final Line line = new Line();
        line.setStrokeWidth(3);
        line.setStroke(Color.RED);

        Label nodeOne = new Label("One");
        nodeOne.setOnMousePressed((event) ->
        {
            drawPoint = new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
            startX = drawPoint.getX();
            startY = drawPoint.getY();
            line.setStartX(startX);
            line.setStartY(startY);

        });

        nodeOne.setOnMouseDragged((event) ->
        {
            line.setEndX(event.getSceneX());
            line.setEndY(event.getSceneY());

            System.out.println("X/Y: " + event.getSceneX() + "/" + event.getSceneY());
        });

        Label nodeTwo = new Label("Two");
        nodeTwo.setLayoutX(100);
        nodeTwo.setLayoutY(100);

        flowGroup.getChildren().addAll(nodeOne, nodeTwo, line);
        root.getChildren().addAll(flowGroup);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JavaFX 8 MouseEvent API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html)

Note that there are multiple X and Y values you can extract from a `MouseEvent`. In this case, you're using `getSceneX()` and `getSceneY()` which gives you coordinates relative to the containing `Scene`.

Also: "MouseDragged" gets called many times, which creates lots of unnecessary calls to `setStartX(...)` + `setStartY(...)`. Consider moving it to "MousePressed", which only gets called once (see below). HTH

```
targetNodeItem.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mEvent) {
        flowLine.setStartX(mEvent.getX());
        flowLine.setStartY(mEvent.getY());
    }           
});

targetNodeItem.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mEvent) {
        //System.out.println("X: " + mEvent.getX() + " Y: " + mEvent.getY());
        flowLine.setEndX(mEvent.getX());
        flowLine.setEndY(mEvent.getY());
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for answering my questions... but it doesn't work.. ;(